# Renaming files with a windows batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, rename

I have a series of files that I need to rename on a daily basis. The files I receive have the following format: yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_xxx.someFileName.txt I need to strip out the time stamp in the middle as well as the three digit field preceeding the filename and leave the date and the "someFileName.txt" piece. The resulting filename should look like: yyyyMMddsomeFileName.txt

I'm pretty clueless when it comes to bat files, I've done some experimenting:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@for %%i in (.\*.txt) do call rename %%i

:rename
@set dateString=%%i:~0,8%
@set nameString=%%i:~20%
@set combinedString=%dateString%%nameString%
@echo %combinedString%
```

Clearly, this doesn't actually rename anything yet. It's just supposed to print the combinedString output. I'm getting a syntax error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect ~0,8 ~20"

What's going on here? What's the correct approach for this?

Comment: You have to `call :rename` (note: colon) to use the label you've defined.

Comment: In addition, many, many things wrong with the syntax, unfortunately. First issue is that batch has no concept of procedures in the HLL sense, and charges straight through labels like `:rename`. You need a `GOTO :EOF` to get to end-of-file after the `FOR` statement. `rename` is a poor choice as it is a batch keyword. Within the routine formerly called `rename`, `%%i` is out-of-context. As it is the first parameter to the `xrename` routine, it is `%1` within the routine. You can't substring metavariables (`%%i`, `%1` etc) - you can only substring ordinary environment variables.

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but if you can get away with a name like yyyyMMdd.someFileName.txt, then all you need is `ren *_*_*.*.txt ????????.*`

Answer (score 1):

#### This should work for what you wanted.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /a:-d /b *.txt') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=_." %%A in ("%%~nxX") do (
        echo %%A%%D
    )
)
```

Replace the `echo` command with `ren "%%~fX" "%%A%%D"` when you want to rename them.

Comment: I want to rename files in a folder like this `20160824.cfx` I use your command and it does not work.. can you tell me where i am going wrong.. I want to rename the existing file to append an incrementing number I have the current directory in a variable in my script as follows `for /r %EFM_TEMP% %%x in (*.cfx) do ren "%%x" "%filename%` it renames only 1 of the 4 files